# How does Omniauth generate auth hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I have worked with `OmniAuth` for social authentication . So when you click on , for example `google login` , it will be redirected to `google` authentication page. Once user allows access, it will be redirected to specified callback url.

This is a `GET` request. And user data will be available with the `auth hash` which is `request.env["omniauth.auth"]`.  What I am unable to understand is , how does the `request` variable get the user data from? The `Get` request only have two parameters `oauth_token` and `oauth_verifier`.

So where does all the User information come from ?